# How to communicate between parent and child without using property binding in Angular?

Tags: angular

is there a way to access data in real time between components without using property binding:

the reason why i can't use it, is because my child component is a dialog and i'm using router-outlet in the app.component.html

Comment: Welcome to the reactive world. You can build a service containing a subject and inject it in both components. The data emitted by the subject will be seen by the two components.

Comment: get set aka getter setters, shared services, subjects, event emitters ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 ways I can think of..

1. using a service with RxJS observables
2. passing data using the dialog component instance
3. using the router `state` { state: {...})

let me give you a brief example for option 1.

**component A sends data**

```
this.sharedService.data(data);
```

**shared-service.ts**

```
private data$ = new Subject<Data>();
dataListener$: Observable<Data> = this.data$.asObservable();
data(data: Data) {
    this.data$.next(data);
}
```

**component B subscribes to the Observable**

```
private readonly onDestoy = new Subject<void>();    

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.sharedService.data$.pipe(
        takeUntil(this.onDestroy) // very important to unsubscribe
        tap((data: Data) => console.log(data)) // here is your data
    ).susbscribe()
}


ngOnDestroy() {
    this.onDestroy.next();
    this.onDestroy.complete();
}
```

I hope it will help you..

Comment: i actually want to remove an element from an array in the parent component not just access data will that help in my case?